How can I parallelize or multithread rviz2 plugins?
Brief summary:
I do some intensive image processing in a custom rviz2 plugin, and I can only get one plugin to generate output at a time. How can I spin each plugin off on a thread so they'll work in parallel?
Background:
My employer uses some proprietary cameras that pack metadata in some extra image rows, so I can't hand the images off directly to the "vanilla" rviz2 ImageDisplay plugin. Additionally, the images are 8 megapixel bayer images, and I'm trying to debayer these. To debayer, I'm visiting each pixel and four neighbors, so I'm touching 5*8 = 40 million pixels per frame.
I've based my custom plugin on the rviz_default_plugins/image_display, and for a single plugin it runs fine. When I add a second plugin, if I'm lucky the second plugin loads one frame and then hangs while the first plugin runs as expected. If I disable the first plugin then the second plugin runs. If I slow the playback down then I can get both plugins to run.
It feels like my processing is overstepping the frame and the second plugin is getting dropped, but I'm not getting any message dropped or QoS notifications from the ros2 bag or rviz2 terminals. From the terminals, it looks like everything's running fine.
ros2 topic hz and ros2 topic bw show both topics are producing at the same rate, same amount of data, so it's not a data production issue, which leaves me to believe it's an rviz2 issue. htop shows the processor isn't super loaded, nvidia-smi actually shows no load on the gpu.
I tried moving the image processing functionality, which happens in processMessage, off into a processMessageImpl and wrapping that in a std::async call, but that didn't improve anything.
My concern is that the plugins are executing "first-enabled, first-run" on a single thread, and again I'm overstepping the allotted time for processing, which kills the second plugin's opportunity to run. I'm assuming I could fix this if I could dispatch the plugins to separate threads, but I don't know how I could control this.

Why do you want to do this work inside rviz2? Why not do the computation in a separate ros node (where you can apply as much parallel processing as you like)?

@Mike973 Scalability and ease of use, basically. The easiest way for people to understand is where the problem originated - Image messages - but I've got custom plugins rendering images on custom messages, and I don't want to force different users to remember to start different processors depending on what needs to be visualized. I was hoping to basically wrap the processMessage call in an async/await or something and be able to process frames in parallel, but that await call is still blocking and I'm not getting the performance I need.

Maybe I could have each instance of a plugin spin up an image processing node, and I can forward the subscribed topic in the background and silently subscribe to the processor output, but that feels like reinventing the wheel.

I am not sure but during a similar case with noetic I found these approaches:

Thread Pool the image processing and the plugins can offload from it to separate threads(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/thread-pool-in-cpp/)
Topic synchronisation (which was my case beacause there was fusion of two sensors)
Queuing or buffering the processed images

Hope this helps.
